# SwiftUI Adding Unnecessary "dot dot dot" to Animated Text

Tags: swift, xcode, text, swiftui, ellipsis

I'm writing an app for iPhone using SwiftUI in XCode.
In one of the views, there is a Text label that changes its text whenever a button is pressed.
The entire view is spring animated, so whenever the text is changed via the button, it is changed with an animation.
The animation works well, except during the animation the Text label adds an unnecessary ellipsis to the end of the text.
I've tried to remove the ellipsis using:

```
Text("text")
    .truncationMode(nil)
```

However, this gives an error.
Is there any way to .turn off the "..." in the Text label?
If not, is there a way to turn off animations for just that Text label without affecting the others, since the entire view is animated?

Comment: Can you please share your code.

Comment: try this: `.lineLimit(nil)`

Answer (score 10):

You can use `Text("text").animation(nil)` to turn off animation.

or you can choose other animations to prevent the `...`

```
Text("text").animation(.spring(response: 0.0, dampingFraction:0.2))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use `minimumScaleFactor(_ factor: CGFloat)`. The text will shrink according to the factor value.

For example, if your font size is 10 and your factor is 0.4, the text font size will be able to decrease down to 4 if needed.

```swift
Text("text")
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
struct UnAnimatedText: View {
    private let text: String
    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {

        }) {
            Text(text)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .animation(nil)
        }
        .disabled(true)
    }
}
```

The text will change without animation but frame of UnAnimatedText - with animations.

.frame(maxWidth: .infinity) is optional, the main idea is to wrap in Button

Comment: I've search a lot about this anomaly.. this line: ".frame(maxWidth: .infinity)" works only. Many thanks!